# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to connect the backend API with react,using componentDidMount but when I did a console.log inside componentDidMount it was not called which means it is not firing The backend API seems to run fine.

```
class Products extends React.Component{
  constructor()
  {
    super()
    this.state={
      productsdetails:null
    }
    
  }
  componentDidMount()

  {   
    fetch('/api/v1/products') 
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((productsdetails) => this.setState({productsdetails:productsdetails }))
  }
  render(){
      console.log(this.state.productsdetails)
    return (
      <div className="body">
        <div className="container">
          {this.state.productsdetails.map((obj) => (
            <Product {...obj} />
          ))}
          
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Products;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just provide valid initial state. The issue is that `this.state.productsdetails` is `null` on the initial render and all subsequent renders until it is updated by the GET request and response.

```
class Products extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state={
      productsdetails: [] // <-- empty array is mappable!
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {   
    fetch('/api/v1/products') 
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((productsdetails) => {
        this.setState({ productsdetails })
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="body">
        <div className="container">
          {this.state.productsdetails.map((obj) => (
            <Product {...obj} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Or alternatively use conditional rendering to render something else until the state is populated. Here I'm rendering nothing (`null`) until `productsdetails` state is truthy.

```
class Products extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state={
      productsdetails: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {   
    fetch('/api/v1/products') 
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((productsdetails) => {
        this.setState({ productsdetails })
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { productsdetails } = this.state;

    if (!productsdetails) return null;

    return (
      <div className="body">
        <div className="container">
          {this.state.productsdetails.map((obj) => (
            <Product {...obj} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```